# Navigation Bar invoke `new file` menu

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

[This video](https://youtu.be/P3yGl4Kfwhs?t=12m20s) shows the following:

[image]

The keyboard shortcut is shown for Mac only (command+N). Is there an equivalent for Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File | New...` -- <kbd>Alt + Insert</kbd> using Default keymap.

**NOTE:**

On Windows (at least when using Default keymap) it shares the same shortcut with `Code | Generate...` .. so the same shortcut will execute different action based on current context/location -- e.g. if invoked in Editor it will execute `Code | Generate` and when invoked while in Project View panel -- `New File`.